# font-size: calc() to make font responsive - is it a good idea?

Tags: css, fonts

I've recently stumbled across tips on using calc() to make font-size more responsive. It's quite simple and as far as I can see well supported by browsers (IE needs a bit of love as always).

```css
body {
  background-color: #434343;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
}

.container {
  padding: 4vw;
}

h1 {
  font-size: calc(24px + 3vw);
}

h2 {
  font-size: calc(20px + 3vw);
}

h3 {
  font-size: calc(16px + 2vw);
}

p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: calc(12px + 1vw);
}

p.hammer {
  font-size: calc(12px + 1.5vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is my main header</h1>
  <h2>This is my subheader</h2>
  <h3>This is my section header</h3>

  <p class="hammer">This is my intro hammer. Wooo.</p>

  <p>This is just a normal paragraph. Calc() is fun and by combining px and vw we can have neat responsive font sizes without too many media queries.</p>

  <p><a href="http://codepen.io/MarkBuskbjerg/pen/QGLepo">To see this applied to a dummy article click here</a> (Opens a new Pen)</p>
</div>
```

**Note** Resize screen to see it in action.

Trick has apparently been around since 2012. However I almost never see this in live sites.

From my perspective it saves a lot of trouble with media queries and reduces CSS.

Is there a downside to this approach that I'm missing, since I almost never see it used?

Comment: It's a fine technique. However, it can make fonts too large at wide screen sizes. To get around that, you can try using "[CSS locking](https://fvsch.com/code/css-locks/)".

Comment: 1vw means 1% of viewport width. 
You can use this way:
h1 {  font-size:24px; font-size:3vw; }
h2 {  font-size: 20px; font-size:3vw;}
h3 {  font-size: 16px; font-size:2vw;}
or @torazaburo share a good idea

Comment: @AmranurRahman Well, that does not do what the OP wants, and it will result in overly small font sizes at narrow screen sizes.

Comment: @AmranurRahman I think this approach will make the font size changes too extreme. 16px + 2vw seems to allow for a more even flow

Comment: @torazaburo Very interesting read. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography.

I made a [demo](http://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/GNExxb) based on the Smashing Magazine article using CSS Custom Properties (CSS Variables) to easily control the min and max font sizes.

Like so:

```
* {
  /* Calculation */
  --diff: calc(var(--max-size) - var(--min-size));
  --responsive: calc((var(--min-size) * 1px) + var(--diff) * ((100vw - 420px) / (1200 - 420))); /* Ranges from 421px to 1199px */
}

h1 {
  --max-size: 50;
  --min-size: 25;
  font-size: var(--responsive);
}

h2 {
  --max-size: 40;
  --min-size: 20;
  font-size: var(--responsive);
}
```